# I want to use SUM() Function from different table

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I have two table shipment and Purchase both of them has the following structure

```
ID, ItemID, Quantity, Date
```

. I want to get the total quantity of an item from shipment - purchase

There is a foreign key to the ID in a third table Item and the structure is

```
ID int auto_increment,
ItemCode VARCHAR(10) unique NOT NULL,
ItemDescription VARCHAR(50),
Price decimal(4,2) DEFAULT 0,
primary key(ID)
```

I have tried to do that with joins, but for some certain reason I am getting more duplicate data each time

Comment: Do you want the total item quantity from both _shipment_ and _purchase_ tables?

Comment: the total from shipment minus the total from purchase

Comment: `Sum Group by`  the `union all` of `shipment` and `- purchase`. Then join with `Items`.

Comment: @Serg Could you write the query I tried but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT SUM(s.Quantity) AS 'shipment sum',
                s.ItemId
         FROM dbo.Shipment s            
         GROUP BY s.ItemId)

     SELECT c.[shipment sum] - b.[purchase sum] AS 'total quantity',i.ItemDescription
     FROM cte AS c
          INNER JOIN
     (
         SELECT SUM(p.quantity) as'purchase sum',
                p.itemid
         FROM dbo.Purchase p            
         GROUP BY p.ItemId
     ) b ON c.itemid = b.itemid
    INNER JOIN item i ON i.id=c.itemid
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want total on all days, ordered by ItemCode

```
select i.ID, i.ItemCode, i.ItemDescription, i.Price, t.Quantity
from Items i
left join (
    select ItemID, sum(Quantity) Quantity
    from (
        select ItemID, Quantity
        from Shipment 
        union all 
        select ItemID, -Quantity
        from Purchase
        ) t
    group by ItemID
    ) t on t.ItemID = i.ID
order by i.ItemCode;
```